# English Error Messages in German Visual Studio 2008 / ASP.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2008, internationalization, locale, custom-errors

This might be a bit weird question, but I'll give it a shot:

HELP, my Visual Studio 2008 / ASP.NET is giving me GERMAN error messages. Besides the fact that translations tend to be not as good as the original text, I can't search for those and find relevant answers to my problems on the internet.

So: How do I switch my German Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition to English locals?

---

Update - Just to make it clear:

I am a German developer, working with a German Windows Vista... I also have a German version of Visual Studio, so it is not surprising, that everything is German. Is just don't want it that way... There must be a way to install english locals into my Visual Studio, though? Or uninstall german ones, so that default english is used?!?

(BTW: Same thing for SQL Server Management Studio, too. F**k "Sichten". I want "Views". That's how you really call them. No one says "Sichten", not even here in Germany, and not even though it is translated correctly).

Comment: Even if this does not fully solve the problem, it was kind of a relief for me: exact english versions of localized error messages: http://finderr.net

Comment: @Marek: haven't tried it yet, but it surely sounds like your link should be an answer, not a comment :-)

Answer (score 8):

Go to the Control Panel -> Software.
There are language packs for .NET (for each version one).
Uninstall them.

Comment: ... unfortunately this does not work for Visual Studio Express 2010... seems when you download it in one language (e.g. German), you are stuck with compiler errors & warnings in that language :-(

Answer (score 4):

You have to switch the user interface language (UI Language) to en-US via Web.Config. This will make sure they are in English.

Comment: Do you know which setting I need to change? I can't find anything related to languages...

Comment: Okay, I found <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />, which at least updates the error messages shown in the browser. The error messages in the Visual Studio UI are still german, but that's better than nothing :(

Comment: Thanks from Russian .net developers as well - I believe Russian translation of error messages is even worse than German - you just saved me :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your system-wide language preferences - 'Regional and Language Options' in WinXP Control Panel. I have found when using VS that my keyboard would go from UK to US mode or even French because the SHIFT + ALT + F10 keystroke is used by VS for showing some context menus and it is also used by Windows as the keystroke for changing system language.

UPDATE:
Check your system-wide language preferences. If necessary install a language pack, though I can't find any on MS Download Center. Otherwise install an English language verison. I am about to download VS 2008 C# Express and I have the option of English, Chinese, French, German, etc.

Comment: I have Visual Studio "Non-Express". I'd like to stay with it. Haven't been able to find a "Non-Express" Download. Shouldn't be a problem to download one (legally), because I'd still use my own serial number.