# How to remove localization .NET Framework of russian?

Tags: .net, windows, localization

I installed Windows 7. Install Visual Studio 2008 with .Net Framework 3.5. Then Russified Windows. And after this error message in Visual Studio suddenly appearing in Russian.
How can I remove a Russian translation for error messages .NET Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Windows->CTRL PANEL->Region and Language -> Location -> Current Location: change from russian to USA

I'm not sure if this is the issue - but you can try this out...

Other [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371651/english-error-messages-in-german-visual-studio-2008-asp-net) answers suggest uninstalling language pack for dot net....

Comment: I have the same issue. Tried your suggestions: still russian

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: VS->Tools->Options->Enviroment->international settings-> then choose appropriate language.

Answer (score 0):

you must set the desired culture of the current thread:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UnlocolizeDotNetFrameworkMessage
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```