# How to know compile-time error code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ide

I thought every compile-time error has its unique code, which I can use to google it. Where can I find it in VS2010?

Another usage would be to find its english equivalent by this code, when I'm not sure how to translate the text of the error (as soon as I use a localized copy of IDE), simply if I just want to ask about the error here on SO.

[image]

Comment: `Right click > Show Error &Help` can be a way. The URL will contain the code, even if you don't have an internet connection.

Comment: +1: @AlvinWong well at least this is a variant, and it works

Comment: You can copy the error from your localized version of the IDE, and use a [Translation site](http://translate.google.com/).

Comment: @JeremyThompson Actually I'm not sure of it's ability to translate. I guess my own translation wouldn't be worse at all. Say, it translated _внедрено_ like _implemented_, while it had to be translated _embedded_. I was not sure about that, and this translator would suggest an incorrect word.

Comment: @AlvinWong you could post your comment as an answer. At least it could get an upvote. While if noone gave me a better way to find the code of an error before this question (I see it can be) is closed as _too localised_ (though I do not think so), I would gladly accept yours, as it can be used to achieve this goal.

Comment: This thread might have an answer or two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371651/english-error-messages-in-german-visual-studio-2008-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And one more way - look in "Output" window (View->Output) and chose "Build" from the dropdown if window shows something else.

`Output:Build` shows raw output of compiler that contains error codes and file names unlike `Errors` window that shows fancy view of the same data. `Output:Build` allows to navigate through errors similar way (double-click for current and `F8`/`Shift+F8` for next/prev error), so may be used interchangebly with `Errors` window (unless you need non-compile errors that show up in errors view).

Comment: Yeah... haven't thought of that. It would save some time if there are not much errors, though not if there are a hundreds.

Comment: I guess this is just what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`Right click > Show Error &Help` can be a way. The URL will contain the code, even if you don't have an internet connection.

I think it should be the third one from the top in your screenshot.

If your final target is to Google the code for the documentation in English, this is more straightforward.

---

Another way is to switch to SharpDevelop, which always show the error code. Of course this would require a switch in IDE and waste your spent money buying Visual Studio.
Also, it will probably come with only English, which doesn't make sense because you could probably switch to English in your Visual Studio.